# Is it possible to change the locale for Outlook's calendar?

Tags: outlook

Why I reply to a meeting in outlook the locale that is used is the system locale. In particular the 'when' label in the reply message is formatted using it. Since I reply internationally, I want to change it (or, in particular, change how the 'when' label is formatted). Is this possible (windows 10, outlook 365)?

Comment: Is this not as task for the client to read the message, and convert the `when` to an appropriate date/time ?  (I do think the sender always uses correct (local) timezone when specifying the `when`)

Answer (score 0):

A system locale is used by default in Outlook. There is no property or method to change the date format in the Outlook object model. You must change the system settings.